# Injective holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

*Suppose $\Omega$ open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\varphi:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function in $\Omega$. If there exists $z_0\in \Omega$ such that $\partial \varphi (z_0)\ne 0$ then exists $U$ neighborhood of $z_0$ where $\varphi_{|U}:U\to\mathbb{C}$ is injective*

I have found the next proof, and I need to understand the reasoning by this way:

*As $\varphi$ is continuous in $z_0$, it must exist $U$ neighborhood of $z_0$ such that $\partial \varphi(z)\ne 0$ for all $z\in U$. It's easy to prove that:
$$\Phi(z,w)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{\varphi(z)-\varphi(w)}{z-w} & z\ne w\\
 \varphi'(z) & z=w
\end{array}\right.$$ 
is continuous in $\Omega\times \Omega$. So then 
\begin{equation}
|\varphi(z_1)-\varphi(z_2)|>\frac{|\varphi'(z_0)|}{2}|z_1-z_2|
\end{equation}
for all $z_1,z_2\in U$.*

I cant understand why the last inequality in true. Any idea?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers with $b\ne 0$ and satisfy the inequality $|a-b|<\frac{|b|}{2},$
 then $$|a|>\frac{|b|}{2}.$$

In fact, $|b|=|(b-a)+a|\le |a-b|+|a|<\frac{|b|}{2}+|a|$. Therefore $\frac{|b|}{2}<|a|$.

Now by the continuity of $\Phi(z,w)$, there exists $U$  neighborhood of $z_0$  such that $$
|\Phi(z_1, z_2)-\varphi^\prime(z_0)|<\varepsilon$$
for all $z_1,$ $z_2$ $\in U, z_1\ne z_2$.
Taking $\varepsilon =\frac{|\varphi^\prime (z_0)|}{2}>0,$ we have
\begin{align}
&\left|\frac{\varphi (z_1)-\varphi (z_2)}{z_1-z_2}-\varphi^\prime(z_0)\right|<\frac{|\varphi (z_0)|}{2},\\
&|\varphi (z_1)-\varphi (z_2)-\varphi^\prime(z_0) (z_1-z_2)|<\frac{|\varphi^\prime (z_0)|}{2}|z_1-z_2|.
\end{align}
Using above inequality with $a=\varphi (z_1)-\varphi (z_2)$ and $b=\varphi^\prime(z_0) (z_1-z_2)$, we  have
$$|\varphi (z_1)-\varphi (z_2)|>\frac{|\varphi^\prime(z_0)|}{2}|z_1-z_2|.$$